# Table of contents in Pelican Blog Generator

Tags: pelican

I know in Pelican I can use the `[TOC]` line for table of contents, but what do I need to do to enable that?

I have to change the `MARKDOWN` setting in `pelicanconf.py` (settings docs are [here](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/settings.html)), but how does that change look like?

Answer (score 11):

Add a `markdown.extensions.toc` key to the `MARKDOWN` dictionary in your pelican configuration file. The key should correspond to a dictionary of configuration options for the Markdown extension.

The following `MARKDOWN` dictionary adds a minimal configuration for the table of contents to the default `MARKDOWN` dictionary specified in the [Pelican documentation](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/settings.html):

```
MARKDOWN = {
  'extension_configs': {
    'markdown.extensions.toc': {
      'title': 'Table of contents:' 
    },
    'markdown.extensions.codehilite': {'css_class': 'highlight'},
    'markdown.extensions.extra': {},
    'markdown.extensions.meta': {},
  },
  'output_format': 'html5',
}
```

Comment: Tx! Perhaps a silly question, but: How do I call/activate that in the templates ?

Comment: Add ``[TOC]`` to your article/page.

Comment: Thank you! Still works as of Pelican 4.2.0 (together with `[TOC]` as per @nwly's comment).